# How to convert date time from UTC to local time zone in xamarin

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin

I want to convert UTC time zone to local time zone.

I use this code to convert from long object to UTC date time.

```
 public class LongToDateTimeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    DateTime _time = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        long dateTime = (long)value;

        return $"{_time.AddSeconds(dateTime).ToString("HH:mm:ss tt")} UTC";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

After I display the utc time zone with this code:

```
 <Label Text="{Binding WeatherDataCurrent.Sys.Sunrise, Converter={StaticResource longToDateTimeConverter}}" 
                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                               Grid.Row="1"
                               Grid.Column="0"
                               TextColor="White"
                               FontAttributes="Bold"/>
```

How to convert this **UTC** time to **local**  time ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tolocaltime?view=net-5.0

Comment: Can you write like a answer to accept it.